# How to fold left a list of BigDecimal? ("overloaded method + cannot be applied")

Tags: scala, bigdecimal, fold

I want to write a short functional sum-function for a List of BigDecimal and tried with:

```
def sum(xs: List[BigDecimal]): BigDecimal = (0 /: xs) (_ + _)
```

But I got this error message:

```
<console>:7: error: overloaded method value + with alternatives:
  (x: Int)Int <and>
  (x: Char)Int <and>
  (x: Short)Int <and>
  (x: Byte)Int
 cannot be applied to (BigDecimal)
       def sum(xs: List[BigDecimal]): BigDecimal = (0 /: xs) (_ + _)
                                                                ^
```

If I use Int instead, that function works. I guess this is because BigDecimal's operator overloading of `+`. What is a good workaround for BigDecimal?

Comment: Note that use can use `reduce` in a situation like this where you don't really need the initial value: `def sum(xs: List[BigDecimal]) = xs.reduce(_ + _)`.

Comment: Hopefully you're doing this for fun and know that there's already a built-in `sum` function that you can use, as in `List(BigDecimal(1.1), BigDecimal(2.2)).sum`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is in inital value. The solution is here and is quite simple:

```
 sum(xs: List[BigDecimal]): BigDecimal = (BigDecimal(0) /: xs) (_ + _)
```

Comment: BTW, most of the scala collections has method `sum` so in that particular case of + operation you can simply write `List(BigDecimal(1), BigDecimal(3)).sum` to get `scala.math.BigDecimal = 4`

Answer (score 2):

foldLeft requires an initialization value.

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

This initialization value (named `z`) has to be of the same type as the type to fold over:

```
(BigDecimal(0) /: xs) { (sum: BigDecimal, x: BigDecimal) => sum+x }
// with syntax sugar
(BigDecimal(0) /: xs) { _+_ }
```

If you add an Int as initialization value the foldLeft will look like:

```
(0 /: xs) { (sum: Int, x: BigDecimal) => sum+x } // error: not possible to add a BigDecimal to Int
```

Answer (score 2):

In a situation like this (where the accumulator has the same type as the items in the list) you can start the fold by adding the first and second items in the list—i.e., you don't necessarily need a starting value. Scala's `reduce` provides this kind of fold:

```
def sum(xs: List[BigDecimal]) = xs.reduce(_ + _)
```

There are also `reduceLeft` and `reduceRight` versions if your operation isn't associative.

Comment: This fails on empty lists, and therefore is not a good solution.

Comment: @Rex, yes, I should have mentioned that. I agree that `foldLeft` is probably the better solution here (if for some reason you didn't want to go with plain old `sum`). But it's still good to know about `reduce`.

Comment: Also, @Jonas (and @Rex), for the record I don't think this should be the accepted answer (which is why I initially made it a comment).

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, you got an error because of initial value, so correct way is to wrap it in BigDecimal. In addition, if you have number of such functions and don't want to write `BigDecimal(value)` everywhere, you can create implicit convert function like this:

```
implicit def intToBigDecimal(value: Int) = BigDecimal(value)
```

and next time Scala will silently convert all your Ints (including constants) to BigDecimal. In fact, most programming languages use silent conversions from integers to decimal or even from decimals to fractions (e.g. Lisps), so it seems to be very logical move.

Comment: Why sprinkle implicit conversions all over the place. If your result is aBugDecimal it makes sense to declare your start value as a BigDecimal.

Comment: @AndreasScheinert: Not all over the place, but in number conversion. Both Java and Scala have a leak of conversion between number types. If you have Int and want to use it in expression with doubles - no problem, Java will convert it to Double for you. So what's the difference between conversion Int => Double (or even Int => Long) and Int => BigDecimal? It is just logical extension to the language. See [this](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-18.html#%_sec_2.5.2) chapter from SICP for more information on this idea.